# When assigning a work item in TFS 2010 to a user i receive the error TF20015

Tags: tfs, tfs-security

When assigning a work item in TFS 2010 to a user i receive the following error

**TF20015: The field 'Assigned To' contains the value 'User Name' that is not in the list of supported values.'**

I tried to remove the user completly from TFS so that i can freshly add the user again, i removed the user from all the projects that i see but the user is still displayed in the 'Assigned To' list

I am having this issue with just one user in our production TFS project but the user do not have any issues in the our TFS test project. By this i think it is not an AD issue. How do i completly remove the user from TFS.

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1):

Solution: User has extra space in the AD account. Space was removed from the AD account but even after removing the user from all the groups user was still in the db. Had to remove the space in the db from the following tables and add the user back to the group 
     [dbo].[ADObjects] 
     dbo.tbl_security_identity_cache 
     dbo.Constants

Answer (score 0):

This link is an overview but I will give you some SIMPLE STEPS below: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/work/office/bulk-add-modify-work-items-excel

1) In TFS use a query to find all work items with this user who no longer exists

2) Save the query (I saved to "My Queries")

3) Run the Query

4) Select Open in Microsoft Office -> Open Query in Excel

5) Excel Opens, Remove the User from the Column for each record, top to bottom blank out that column

6) Click Publish and it will put all of those Work Items back WITHOUT his/her name on them

- Done